# Why are the leaves green?

Tags: visible-light, wavelength, molecules

My professor mentioned in yesterday's class that the color of the leaves can be explained by evolution, that they adapted to reflect the green color because the sun has its peak right about there:

[image: Spectrum of the Sun.]

He said, however, he was not fully aware of the mechanism, but it's quite possible that having another host star, we'd observe (for instance) blue leaves.

All the pages I've checked this far include the explanation mentioning that "chlorophyll gives leaves their green color" but nothing is further noted.

When I come to think of this, I think of green as a sort of "saddle point", below above which the leaf is not likely to appear and below which it goes even farther down and finally dies as we know it.

[image: Leaf color VS lifetime graph]

The graph below the midpoint (green) is the one everyone sees at autumn. I added the curves above as a hypothesis (if there's any reason for leaf to become bluish, the process is probably unstable and goes straight back to being green).

My intuitive explanation is that for some reason when the leaf starts absorbing (thus, stops reflecting) the light of high intensity, this high intensity helps the process of chlorophyll breaking down, thus it absorbs more and more green until finally it degrades.

Peak intensity light (green, for our case) seems to be "killing" the leaves. Having all sorts of leaves at the beginning, probably only the ones containing chlorophyll (which allows them to reflect these deadly rays) survived.

I know this is more of a chemistry/biology question (or, at least, a molecular physics one), but I'd still want to ask if anyone can explain the mechanism in details.

Comment: Related Quora question (possible answer): https://www.quora.com/Why-did-chlorophyl-evolve-to-be-green-as-opposed-to-black-which-would-absorb-more-energy

Comment: Related biology SE question: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/450/why-do-plants-have-green-leaves-and-not-red

Comment: A total guess: that green is related to a balance between the (too high) energy of blue , and the (too low) energy of red. Apologies if you have made this point already. That's very vague, I know, but so is my knowledge of photosynthesis, sorry.

Comment: I'm voting this question as off topic because it is not about physics.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Why_are_plants_green

Comment: You've obviously given this much more thought than your teacher. As the Biology SE question asks : Why is it an advantage to reflect green light? It is tempting to think that evolution produces the most efficient solutions. Not true. Change only happens when there is some local *pressure* such as competition for food, or declining resources. Without incentive, a *good enough* solution isn't improved upon. I like Tobias Kienzler's comment : *Maybe in most cases absorbing green was just the first thing that happened (by evolution) and it was sufficient, but I'm just speculating.*

Comment: I don't think physics can answer this question. It is better suited to Biology SE but might be closed there as a duplicate. It is a good question, but there is no clear answer. It is difficult to find a suitable place where it can be discussed. Perhaps you can air you ideas in the Biology SE chatroom.

Comment: Call this a coincidence, but I found this article this morning: http://phys.org/news/2016-11-team-combines-quantum-physics-photosynthesis.html

Comment: An ELI5 (so not very detailed unfortunately) with some insight regarding this question https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/3chhdg/eli5_why_do_some_plants_have_red_leaves_instead/